# Strip of tags from text extracted from XML

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am parsing XML documents. I do `getTextContent()` to get text from particular section that I want. The text that I get has tags like

```
<italic> </italic>
<sub> </sub>
```

..and some more. I want to strip of these tags and just keep the text, irrespective of what the tags are.

My document looks like this

```
<article>
   <sec>Section 1</sec>  
   <sec>Section 2
      <title>Title1</title>
      <sec>
         <title>Subtitle1</title>
         <p>........<italic> </italic>...</p>
      </sec>
      <sec>
         <title>Subtitle2</title>
         <p>........<sub> </sub>...</p>
      </sec>
   </sec>
</article>
```

I need all the text in `<p>...</p>` without the tags in it.
How can I go about it? I was thinking of identifying all the tags and replacing it with `""`. But there has to be a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Try to focus your question. If you are parsing XML, why do you want to remove tags? What is you input and what output do you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could apply this reg ex to the results of getTextContent()

```
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a perl script to go through the file then use `s/ \< .* \>  //xg;` to get rid of all the tags.